# Class based views: FormView, How to access variable from form_valid() in success_url()

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a simple email form that works fine but I want to access `recipient` in `success_url()` so I can have a simple "email has been sent to `recipient`" message in the success template.

```
class FullEmailView(FormView, MyCustomMixin):
    form_class = EmailForm
    template_name = 'my_app/email_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        x = MyModel.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        recipient = form.cleaned_data.get('email_address')
        subject = "My Email Subject"
        sender = "me@myemail.com>"
        html_message = render_to_string('my_app/email.html', {
            'x': x,
            'recipient': recipient,
        })
        message = render_to_string('my_app/email.html')
        send_mail(
            subject,
            message,
            sender,
            [recipient],
            html_message = html_message
        ) 
        return super(FullEmailView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self, form, **kwargs):
        x = MyModel.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        recipient =  #????  <<<--- what do I put here to access recipient from from_valid()?
        return super(FullEmailView, self).reverse_lazy('email_sent', self, kwargs={"pk": x.pk})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use the **messages** framework of django

Use the following code to add your message:

```
  messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Email has been sent!')
```

So your form_valid() function can be changed like :

```
  from django.contrib import messages
   #... 
   def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
          x = MyModel.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
          recipient = form.cleaned_data.get('email_address')
          subject = "My Email Subject"
          sender = "me@myemail.com>"
          html_message = render_to_string('my_app/email.html', {
          'x': x,
        'recipient': recipient,
         })
    message = render_to_string('my_app/email.html')
    send_mail(
        subject,
        message,
        sender,
        [recipient],
        html_message = html_message
    ) 
     messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Email has been sent!')
    return super(FullEmailView, self).form_valid(form)
 #....
```

The message can be accessed on the template by

```
 {% if messages %}
 <ul class="messages">
   {% for message in messages %}
    <li>{{ message }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
 </ul>
 {% endif %}
```

More about messages : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: perfect! thanks very much:  messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, recipient) worked like a champ.